# Clearing STL in dedicated thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, c++11

In one of my projects, I identified a call to `std::deque<T>::clear()` as a major bottleneck.

I therefore decided to move this operation in a dedicated, low-priority thread:

```
template <class T>
void SomeClass::parallelClear(T& c)
{
    if (!c.empty())
    {
        T* temp = new T;
        c.swap(*temp);   // swap contents (fast)

        // deallocate on separate thread
        boost::thread deleteThread([=] () { delete temp; } );

        // Windows specific: lower priority class
        SetPriorityClass(deleteThread.native_handle(), BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS);
    }
}

void SomeClass:clear(std::deque<ComplexObject>& hugeDeque)
{
   parallelClear(hugeDeque);
}
```

This seems to work fine (VisualC++ 2010), but I wonder if I overlooked any major flaw. I would welcome your comments about the above code.

**Additional information**:

`SomeClass:clear()` is called from a GUI-thread, and the user interface is unresponsive until the call returns. The `hugeQueue`, on the other hand, is unlikely to be accessed by that thread for several seconds after clearing.

Comment: Is it slow even if you run without the debugger attached?

Comment: STL containers themselves aren't thread safe, so your code should take that as a premise before doing operations on containers in a multi threaded environment.

Comment: Yes. The deque I'm actually using contains millions of objects (not ints)

Comment: @DumbCoder: I'm not accessing any given container from several threads.

Comment: Cool idea, would you mind sharing what sort of improved performance you're seeing after implementing this?

Comment: As an example, I filled the container with 100'000 objects (size roughly 100 bytes / object). I didn't measure exactly, but using a stopwatch... Without parallel delete, on a Core 2 Duo, it would take about 1 second before `clear()` returns. With parallel delete, it returns almost immediately. Of course, you loose deterministic destruction, rather like using a garbage collector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only valid if you guarantee that access to the heap is serialized. Windows *does* serialize access to the primary heap by default, but it's possible to turn this behaviour off and there's no guarantee that it holds across platforms or libraries. As such, I'd be careful depending on it- make sure that it's explicitly noted that it depends on the heap being shared between threads and that the heap is thread-safe to access.

I personally would simply suggest using a custom allocator to match the allocation/deallocation pattern would be the best performance improvement here- remember that creating threads has a non-trivial overhead.

Edit: If you are using GUI/Worker thread style threading design, then really, you should create, manage *and* destroy the deque on the worker thread.

Comment: @DeadMG: one can turn off serialization on a per-system basis? Or is this a compile-time setting?

Comment: So in this custom allocator, you'd use a dedicated heap, which you deallocate all at once when clearing?

Comment: @Daniel: As far as I know, you can change the settings at runtime. As for your custom allocator, I don't know enough about your allocation patterns- but if you have a single very large object and series of deallocations, then it may well be worth it to just deallocate a whole heap. Of course, you still have to destruct the objects involved.

Comment: "make sure that it's explicitly noted" - and beware that in code that's otherwise single-threaded, turning this on might cost you more than clearing at low priority saves you. Even aside from the cost of creating the thread itself, if your low-priority thread immediately starts running on your second core, and your main thread is doing a lot of allocation/freeing in general, then you might have created a load of contention. So "seems to work" could turn into "doesn't work" if you don't watch it like a hawk.

Comment: @Steve: The Windows heap is serialized and thread-safe by default. You don't turn it on and all ST-code uses the serialized heap anyway.

Comment: @DeadMG: I'll try the custom allocator (I'm aware of the fact that destruction of the actual elements needs to be dealt with, too). But I'm unsure how to deallocating the whole heap interacts with the `deque`. I'll probably just have to make sure that it's destructor doesn't run.

Comment: @Steve: I'm aware of the contention issue. But my usage pattern (see update to the question) makes it unlikely to become a problem.

Comment: @DeadMG: OK, but the only purpose of documenting that the heap must be thread-safe (as you recommended) is in case someone, somewhere, has turned it off. They will then turn it on and take the hit for serialization. *In addition* to the hit for serializing in an otherwise single-threaded program that was using the optimization, there's a further potential hit for contention when you try this kind of trick, although apparently not in this case. The point being that ideally what you want here is "free when the system is idle", which isn't necessarily the same as "free in a low-priority thread".

Comment: @Steve: You may also care to note that a custom allocator is my actual suggested solution.

Comment: @DeadMG: I implemented an allocator using a series of fixed-size pools. Performance is indeed very good and I'm going to stick with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware, that its not sure that this will improve the overall performance of your application. The windows standard heap (also the Low fragmentation heap) is not laid out for frequently transmitting allocation information from one thread to another. This will work, but it might produce quite an overhead of processing.

The documentation of the hoard memory allocator might be a starting point do get deeper into that:
http://www.cs.umass.edu/~emery/hoard/hoard-documentation.html

Your approach will though improve responsiveness etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my case, the heap will typically be accessed 1'000'000 times from thread A, then the same amount from thread B (to deallocate the objects allocated by A), and so on. So I'm not switching very often. But I'll check out alternatives with specific allocators (the remaining part of the application already implements and uses it's own specific memory management routines).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the things mentioned by the other posters you should consider if the objects contained in the collection have a thread affinity, for example COM objects in single threaded apartment may not be amenable to this kind of trick.